# Using a long double or just a double for calculating pi?

Tags: c++, math, loops, floating-point, pi

I'm calculating pi using a long winded formula. I'm trying to get more familiar with floating point numbers etc. I have a working program that uses doubles. The problem with my code is:

1. If I use a double, pi is only accurate to the 7th decimal place. I can't get it to be any more accurate.
2. If I use a long double, pi is accurate up to the 9th decimal place however the code takes much longer to run. If I check for precision for less than 0.00000001 using a long double, pi returns a value of 9.4246775. I assume that this is due to the long double.

My question is what is the most accurate variable type? How could I change my code to improve the precision of pi?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 double arctan;
 double pi;
 double precision;
 double previous=0;
 int y=3;
 int loopcount=0;

   cout<<"Start\n";

   arctan=1-(pow(1,y)/y);

 do
   {
     y=y+2;
     arctan=arctan+(pow(1,y)/y);
     y=y+2;
     arctan=arctan-(pow(1,y)/y);

      pi=4*(arctan);

    //  cout<<"Pi is: ";
    //  cout<<setprecision(12)<<pi<<endl;

      precision=(pi*(pow(10,10)/10));

      loopcount++;

      if(precision-previous<0.000000001)
        break;

      previous=precision;
    }
  while(true);

  cout<<"Pi is:"<<endl;
       cout<<setprecision(11)<<pi<<endl;
  cout<<"Times looped:"<<endl;
       cout<<loopcount<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should consider switching to a fixed point representation if you want tight control over precision.

Comment: When you changed to `long double`, did you change _all_ the API calls, e.g. `pow()` to `powl()`, `arctan()` to the `atanl()`-equivalent, etc?

Comment: Doug, would you mind explaining that? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: sarnold, I changed all instances of a double in my variables to a long double. I didn't rename any of the variables though. How would that make a difference?

Comment: Renaming the variables would not make any difference but you would have use the correct methods (API's) in accordance with your variable types. That's what sarnold was saying.

Comment: Also, to what precision do you want it?

Comment: I want it to 10 decimal places or more. Didn't realise that those methods could be different between doubles and long doubles. Will look into that

Comment: Why do you want it to "10 decimal places or more?"  It seems suspicious that you get 9 digits now and you want just one more.  Why not just hard-code the constant?

Comment: It can be 12 it can be 20... As I said I am trying to better understand the workings of floating points and working with them so hard coding the constant is not exactly beneficial. I want to know why it works out to 9 with no problems, however going to 10 causes a very different result. That's why 10...

Comment: @sarnold: Not true. That is for C code. The C++ code has overload version of pow() for all the types (becuase it can and C can't). You just need to make sure you use the C++ header: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

Comment: See also: `26.4.7 complex value operations [complex.value.ops]`

Comment: @Loki: Thanks! I hadn't realized C++ allowed overloading functions/methods on primitives. (There's a _lot_ I don't know about C++, obviously.)

Comment: what compiler are you using?  Also, can I suggest you check that y isn't overflowing?

Comment: `pow(1,y)`? what? why calculating again and again an expression that's equal to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the max limits of doubles/long doubles from std::numeric_limits

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "     Double::digits10:  " << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Long Double::digits10:  " << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << "\n";
}
```

On my machine this gives:

```
     Double::digits10:  15
Long Double::digits10:  18
```

So I expect long double to be accurate to 18 digits.
The definition of this term can be found here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/

Standard quote: `18.3.2 Numeric limits [limits]`

Also Note: As the comment is way down in the above list:

That @sarnold is incorrect (though mysteriously he has two silly people up-voting his comment without checking) in his assertions on pow(). What he states is only applicable to C. C++ has overloads for the types because in C++ pow() is a template function. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/ in the standard at `26.4.7 complex value operations [complex.value.ops]`

Comment: That's a great answer thanks for that. Couldn't see anything about those limits and I've done a lot of reading on this. Thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: Quick question for you though. If a long double is accurate to 18 places, why am I getting a value of 9.454665... for pi after I change the level of accuracy to <0.000000001?

Comment: What are the values on your machine. These values are not universal.

Comment: Note. It is not accurate to 18 places. It is accurate to 18 digits (that includes the 3). The bigger the number above the decimal point the less digits below the decimal point you  get.

Comment: As of the 1999 standard, C also has type-generic versions of `pow()` and other functions in `<tgmath.h>`. As of the 2011 standard, `_Generic` permits users to write similar functions.

Comment: The nice thing about using `std::numeric_limits` is that it will adjust to compiler settings, such as those that would enable `long double` to be equivalent iEEE 128-bit floating point.

Answer (score 1):

The predefined floating-point type with the greatest precision is `long double`.

There are three predefined floating-point types:

- `float` has at least 6 decimal digits of precision
- `double` has at least 10, and at least as many as `float`
- `long double` has at least 10, and at least as many as `double`

These are minimum requirements; any or all of these types could have more precision.

If you need more precision than `long double` can provide, you might look at [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which supports arbitrary precision (at considerable expense in speed and memory usage).

Answer (score -3):

Or, you could just hard-code the digits of PI and see what happens.  ^_^

http://www.joyofpi.com/pi.html