# C++ determining if a number is an integer

Tags: c++, int, double, decimal

I have a program in C++ where I divide two numbers, and I need to know if the answer is an integer or not. What I am using is:

> if(fmod(answer,1) == 0)

I also tried this:

> if(floor(answer)==answer)

The problem is that answer usually is a 5 digit number, but with many decimals. For example,  answer can be: `58696.000000000000000025658` and the program considers that an integer.

Is there any way I can make this work?

I am dividing `double a/double b= double answer`

(sometimes there are more than 30 decimals)

Thanks!

EDIT:
a and b are numbers in the thousands (about 100,000) which are then raised to powers of 2 and 3, added together and divided (according to a complicated formula). So I am plugging in various a and b values and looking at the answer. I will only keep the a and b values that make the answer an integer. An example of what I got for one of the answers was: 218624 which my program above considered to be an integer, but it really was: 218624.00000000000000000056982 So I need a code that can distinguish integers with more than 20-30 decimals.

Comment: Should true be reported only for numbers slightly greater than an integer and not for numbers slightly less than an integer, such as 2.999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875? How much difference is acceptable? How did you come to have numbers that should be integers or not (what prior calculations gave rise to this)? Where did `a` and `b` in your `a/b` example come from?

Comment: a and b are numbers in the thousands (about 100,000) which are then raised to powers of 2 and 3, added together and divided (according to a complicated formula). So I am plugging in various a and b values and looking at the answer. I will only keep the a and b values that make the answer an integer. An example of what I got for one of the answers was: 218624 which my program above considered to be an integer, but it really was: 218624.00000000000000000056982 So I need a code that can distinguish integers with more than 20-30 decimals.

Comment: @ItM You will not be able to do that with the precision of a `double`.  You'd need to use a high precision floating point library.

Comment: I was considering GMP but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: 218624.00000000000000000056982 cannot be represented as a `double` in the format most C++ implementations use. Did you obtain this result in `double` (implying your implementation uses a very long format for `double`), obtain it in `long double` or another built-in type in a C++ program (possibly a type that is an extension in your implementation), obtain it with other software, or obtain it by other mathematics (e.g., pen and paper)? Is it an example of a number that should be treated as an integer because the fractional part is only the result of floating-point approximations or…

Comment: … an example of a number that should not be treated as an integer because it is not, even though the fractional part is very small? Also, you may need to describe how values are divided “according to a complicated formula”. We cannot calculate bounds on the errors that might arise during calculation if we do not know the calculations.

Comment: If you have numbers `a` and `b` exactly, you can test whether `a/b` is exactly an integer without dividing them by comparing `fmod(a, b)` to zero. The `fmod` function (if implemented properly) returns an exact result, with no rounding error, even if the exact result of `a/b` would have a rounding error. Thus, this test avoids one problem of floating-point arithmetic. However, if `a` and `b` might already have rounding errors, we need more information about them in order to be able to determine whether the errors are within bounds that let us distinguish whether an integer would ideally result.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the OP has not answered questions to clarify the problem. The answers so far suggest ways to accept as an integer a non-integer computed value that would be an integer if computed exactly, but they have problems: They do not provide a way to determine the tolerance to use, they falsely accept as integers values that would be non-integers if computed exactly, and they do not solve the actual problem, which is that, due to limited precision, the computed value is an integer but the exact value would not be (the opposite of what the answers address).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::modf` in `cmath.h`:

```
double integral;
if(std::modf(answer, &integral) == 0.0)
```

The integral part of `answer` is stored in `fraction` and the return value of `std::modf` is the fractional part of `answer` with the same sign as `answer`.

Comment: Why would you name the integral part `fraction`?

Comment: @DwayneTowell Maybe because its over 05:00 and I am still awake. Thanks edited :)

Comment: Because of the way floating point numbers are stored in memory, you don't want to do the `== 0.0` check.  Instead, you will want to do `std::modf(answer, &integral) < SOME_REALLY_SMALL_NUMBER`.

Comment: This does not provide the requested operation, which is to report true for numbers that are close to integers. And, even if were modified to report true if the fraction part is very small, it will continue to report false for numbers such as 2.999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, which I suspect the OP prefers true.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to check if the number is within a very short distance of an integer, like this:

```
bool isInteger(double a){
    double b=round(a),epsilon=1e-9; //some small range of error
    return (a<=b+epsilon && a>=b-epsilon); 
}
```

This is needed because floating point numbers have limited precision, and numbers that indeed are integers may not be represented perfectly. For example, the following would fail if we do a direct comparison:

```
double d=sqrt(2); //square root of 2
double answer=2.0/(d*d); //2 divided by 2
```

Here, `answer` actually holds the value `0.99999...`, so we cannot compare that to an integer, and we cannot check if the fractional part is close to 0.
In general, since the floating point representation of a number can be either a bit smaller or a bit bigger than the actual number, it is not good to check if the fractional part is close to 0. It may be a number like `0.99999999` or `0.000001` (or even their negatives), these are all possible results of a precision loss. That's also why I'm checking both sides (`+epsilon` and `-epsilon`). You should adjust that `epsilon` variable to fit your needs.

Also, keep in mind that the precision of a `double` is close to [15 digits](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/). You may also use a `long double`, which may give you some extra digits of precision (or not, it is up to the compiler), but even that only gets you around [18 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796900/1560509). If you need more precision than that, you will need to use an external library, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Floating point numbers are stored in memory using a very different bit format than integers.  Because of this, comparing them for equality is not likely to work effectively.  Instead, you need to test if the difference is smaller than some *epsilon*:

```
const double EPSILON = 0.00000000000000000001; // adjust for whatever precision is useful for you
double remainder = std::fmod(numer, denom);
if(std::fabs(0.0 - remainder) < EPSILON)
{
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to include values that are close to integers (based on your desired precision), you can modify the if condition slightly (since the remainder returned by `std::fmod` will be in the range `[0, 1)`):

```
if (std::fabs(std::round(d) - d) < EPSILON)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can see the test for this [here](http://ideone.com/UqGsVI).

Floating point numbers are generally somewhat precise to about 12-15 digits (as a `double`), but as they are stored as a mantissa (fraction) and a exponent, rational numbers (integers or common fractions) are not likely to be stored as such.  For example,

```
double d = 2.0; // d might actually be 1.99999999999999995
```

Because of this, you need to compare the difference of what you expect to some very small number that encompasses the precision you desire (we will call this value, *epsilon*):

```
double d = 2.0;
bool test = std::fabs(2 - d) < epsilon; // will return true
```

So when you are trying to compare the remainder from `std::fmod`, you need to check it against the difference from `0.0` (not for actual equality to `0.0`), which is what is done above.

Also, the `std::fabs` call prevents you from having to do 2 checks by asserting that the value will always be positive.

If you desire a precision that is greater than 15-18 decimal places, you cannot use `double` or `long double`; you will need to use a high precision floating point library.

Comment: This will report false for numbers slightly less than integers, such as 2.999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, but I suspect the OP prefers true. Additionally, the OP likely needs help figuring out what value should be used for `EPSILON`, so writing “adjust for whatever precision is useful for you” is not helpful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That depends on what he selects as `EPSILON`, but I'll expound a bit.

Comment: There is still no code here that will work. `std::fabs(0.0 - remainder) < EPSILON` does not work because `remainder` is not near zero when `numer` is slightly below an integer; it is near one. And the code `bool test = std::fabs(2 - d) < epsilon;` only works to test for two; it does not show how one might get another integer to test against.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The actual tests disagree with you:  http://ideone.com/HVcCe0 as does the math (when a floating point number `x` is close to an integer number `y`, `|x - y|` will be close to `0`, not close to `1`.  If it is close to `1` (or any other number other than 0), the remainder indicates that the numerator is not evenly divisible by the denominator.

Comment: The `double numer = 1.9999999999999999999999999;` in your test code does not result in `numer` being slightly less than two. It results in exactly two. Try `double numer = nexttoward(2, 0);`.

Comment: `std::nexttoward` is going to give you a distinct value less than 2 (when using 0) that will **not** be divisible by a whole number (in this case, `1.99999999999999977796` - which is not the same as `1.999999999999999` nor is it the same as `2.0`).  The only way to do what you are implying (which is different than what the OP is asking) is to first round the floating point numbers to a given precision.